# How to write Junit Test cases for GCP BigQuery in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, google-bigquery, mockito, junit4

I want to write the JUnit test for BigQuery but I don't know where to start from. I looked into many examples but wasn't able to understand any references. Providing you a sample code for Bigquery.

```
public void insertRows(String projectId, String datasetName,  String auditTableName, String tableInserted, Boolean status) {
        try {

            Map rowContent = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            rowContent.put("tableProcessed", tableInserted);
            rowContent.put("dateProcessed", LocalDate.now().toString());
            rowContent.put("success", success);

            BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryUtil.getConnection(projectId);

            // Get table
            TableId tableId = TableId.of(datasetName, auditTableName);

            InsertAllResponse response = bigquery.insertAll(InsertAllRequest.newBuilder(tableId)
                .addRow(rowContent).build());

            if (response.hasErrors()) {
                // If any of the insertions failed, this lets you inspect the errors
                for (Map.Entry<Long, List<BigQueryError>> entry : response.getInsertErrors().entrySet()) {
                    log.error("Response error: \n" + entry.getValue());
                }
            }
            log.info("Rows successfully inserted into table");
        } catch (BigQueryException e) {
            log.error("Insert operation not performed \n" + e.toString());
        }
    }
```